# package does not exist when building WAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, war

I have a JavaEE maven project where I'm referencing a third-party library stored in WEB-INF/lib. When I build the project maven complains that package com.thirdparty.common does not exists. I changed the project to use maven-war-plugin and added the following configuration to include all libs in WEB-INF:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm assuming that maven is not loading these third-party dependencies. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should reference the jar in the dependencies section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/104891.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem